# Android database accessible for ALL activities to read from

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, sqliteopenhelper

UPDATE: I needed to override the onDestroy method to close the Database Helper class object.  Works fine now. Just add this in any activity where you create an object of your SQLiteOpenHelper class.

```
Database dbHelper; //in class
dbHelper = new Database(this, "pulling data",null,1); //in onCreate

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

I create and update a database from a fragment with data that comes in about every 2 seconds from sensors that are connected over Bluetooth to my Android app.

I go to different activities in my app and those activities should be able to read from the database to display the data in a list/textview, but the issue is that the context in which the database was created and is getting updated is from a fragment.  Is there a way to make it so that all activities can read from the database?

I created a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, where you can access functions to do CRUD operations, but once I go into another activity and I query the database the cursor pulls nothing up although I inserted and am updating the database in the background from a fragment.

Heads up, I'm pretty new to Android dev and have looked at other questions/solutions but nothing works for me. Appreciate any tutorials or advice to get going, thanks!

Below is my SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public Context DBcontext = null;
    //DatabaseContract version
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Sensors";



    public static final String SENSOR_DATA_TABLE_NAME ="SensorData";
    public static final String SENSOR_DATA_COLUMN_ID = "SensorDataID";
    public static final String NODE_COLUMN_NAME = "Nodes";
    public static final String TEMP_COLUMN_NAME = "TemperatureData";
    public static final String MOTION_COLUMN_NAME = "MotionData";
    public static final String GAS_COLUMN_NAME = "GasData";
    public static final String LIGHT_COLUMN_NAME = "LightData";



    //Constructor for the Database activity
    public DatabaseContract( Context context , String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super( context, name, factory, version);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+SENSOR_DATA_TABLE_NAME+" ("+SENSOR_DATA_COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+NODE_COLUMN_NAME+ " STRING, "+TEMP_COLUMN_NAME+" STRING,     "+MOTION_COLUMN_NAME+" STRING, "+GAS_COLUMN_NAME+" STRING, "+ LIGHT_COLUMN_NAME+" STRING)");


    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SENSOR_DATA_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public boolean checkExist()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ SENSOR_DATA_TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);


        if(res.getCount() > 0){
            res.close();
            return true;
        }else {
            res.close();
            return false;
        }


    }



    public void updateSensorData(String node_number, String temp_data, String motion_data, String light_data, String gas_data)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + SENSOR_DATA_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + NODE_COLUMN_NAME + " ='" + node_number + "'";
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);



       if (res.getCount() == 0){
           res.close();
           ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
           content.put(NODE_COLUMN_NAME, node_number);
           content.put(TEMP_COLUMN_NAME, temp_data);
           content.put(MOTION_COLUMN_NAME, motion_data);
           content.put(GAS_COLUMN_NAME, gas_data);
           content.put(LIGHT_COLUMN_NAME, light_data);
           db.insert(SENSOR_DATA_TABLE_NAME, null, content);


       }else{

           /**try to get ID from cursor, not working so hardcoded 1 for now to test**/
           //String ID = Long.toString(res.getLong(res.getColumnIndex(SENSOR_DATA_COLUMN_ID)));
           ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
           contentValues.put(NODE_COLUMN_NAME, node_number);
           contentValues.put(TEMP_COLUMN_NAME, temp_data);
           contentValues.put(MOTION_COLUMN_NAME, motion_data);
           contentValues.put(GAS_COLUMN_NAME, gas_data);
           contentValues.put(LIGHT_COLUMN_NAME, light_data);

           //hardcoded ID = 1 just for testing
           db.update(SENSOR_DATA_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, SENSOR_DATA_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ", new String[] { "1" } );


       }


    }


}
```

Below is the fragment that interacts with the class from above to insert/update data in the database.  I took the Google BluetoothChat app and modified it to work for my intended purpose. This fragment interacts with the Database class in the handler for MESSAGE_READ. I parse the data sent to me, then pass it as parameters to the Database function updateSensorData where it takes care of inserting then thereafter updating the data.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Bluetooth extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "Bluetooth";

    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

    // Layout Views
    private Button scan_button;
    private Button move;
    private DatabaseContract dbHelper;

    /**
     * Name of the connected device
     */
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;


    /**
     * Local Bluetooth adapter
     */
    private BluetoothAdapter BAdapter = null;

    /**
     * Member object for the chat services
     */
    private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        BAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


        if (BAdapter == null)
        {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    .setTitle("Error: Not compatible")
                    .setMessage("Your phone does not support Bluetooth")
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        if (!BAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        }
        else if (mChatService == null)
        {
            setupChat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mChatService != null)
        {
            mChatService.stop();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
        // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
        // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
        if (mChatService != null)
        {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
            if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE)
            {
                // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                mChatService.start();
            }
        }
        scan_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceList.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bluetooth, container, false);

        Button move = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.move);
        move.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Network.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        scan_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        move = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.move);
    }

    /**
     * Set up the UI and background operations for chat.
     */
    private void setupChat()
    {

        scan_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceList.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);

            }
        });


        // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(getActivity(), mHandler);


    }



    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1)
                    {
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connected to "+mConnectedDeviceName+" setting up network. . .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            final Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    move.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    scan_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            }, 4000);

                            break;
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connecting. . .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:

                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:

                            scan_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            move.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;

                /******************************** where this fragment interacts with SQLiteOpenHelper class for database******************************/


                case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                    dbHelper = new DatabaseContract(getActivity(), "data transfer for sensors", null, 1);

                    int node = readMessage.indexOf("node");
                    int temp_number = readMessage.indexOf("t");
                    int motion_number = readMessage.indexOf("m");
                    int light_number = readMessage.indexOf("l");
                    int gas_number = readMessage.indexOf("g");

                    String node_number = readMessage.substring(node + 5, node + 6);
                    String temp_data = readMessage.substring(temp_number, motion_number);
                    String motion_data = readMessage.substring(motion_number, light_number);
                    String light_data = readMessage.substring(light_number, gas_number);
                    String gas_data = readMessage.substring(gas_number);

                    dbHelper.updateSensorData(node_number, temp_data, motion_data, light_data, gas_data);


                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    // save the connected device's name
                    mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);

                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    //automatically invoked when app starts up
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
                // When DeviceList returns with a device to connect
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    connectDevice(data, false);
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                    setupChat();
                }
                else
                {
                    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .setTitle("Error")
                            .setMessage("Bluetooth is disabled")
                            .setPositiveButton("ENABLE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {

                                    Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                                    startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 8);
                                    onDestroy();
                                    onResume();
                                }
                            })
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();
                }
        }
    }


    private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean insecure)
    {
        // Get the device MAC address
        String address = data.getExtras()
                .getString(DeviceList.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object
        BluetoothDevice device = BAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        // Attempt to connect to the device
        mChatService.connect(device, insecure);
    }


}
```

Below is an example of one of the different classes that needs to access the information in the database. I test it with the checkExist() function and it returns false although in the fragment I do successfully insert then update the sensor data. This is where my problem lies, not sure why it isn't pulling anything from the database

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**Here is an example of one of the activities that needs to pull readings from the database to display**/

public class NodeData extends AppCompatActivity
{


    private DatabaseContract dbHelper;
    private TextView tempDisplay;
    private TextView motionDisplay;
    private TextView gasDisplay;
    private TextView lightDisplay;
    private ListView dataDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nodedata);
        String node_number = getIntent().getExtras().getString("node_number");
        String label = "Node "+node_number+" Data";
        TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.node_data_label);
        textViewToChange.setText(label);


        dbHelper = new DatabaseContract(getApplicationContext(), "data transfer for sensors", null, 1);


        boolean test = dbHelper.checkExist();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testing: "+test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```

Comment: Please share you code of the of the "activity that extends SQLiteOpenHelper"

Comment: @SagiMymon just added, thanks I completely spaced that out.

Comment: This is just a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper and not an Activity. it's important for you to understand that if you're new to Android. Can you share also an activity both activities that uses it? i mean the activity that it works with and the one that no.

Comment: @SagiMymon you're right I didn't mean to call it an Activity I know the difference. Just added the code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extends LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks in your activity to load the data from the data base.

For more information you can read that:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Answer (score 0):

See this:
http://guides.codepath.com/android/local-databases-with-sqliteopenhelper

1. I would recommend you to use the singleton pattern to avoid leak and to re-allocate the db each time.
2. It's highly recommended to use startTransaction and endTransaction as described in the link above.

If it still doesn't work, i also recommend to you to use Loaders as @Bruno suggested.

Regardless your question, just a small potential bug fix -  In `Database` class in function `updateSensorData` you forgot to close the `Cursor` in the else flow.